# What is the EmbeddedAppDeltas folder in Xcode and can I delete it safely?

Tags: xcode, xcode7

On my computer there's a folder of nearly 1GB in size at the following path:
  /private/var/folders/ph/q7jl9fz115g104hfgpsw5k6w0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/All/Xcode/EmbeddedAppDeltas

It remains there no matter whether I delete build folders or not. It appears to have every version of my app that I've ever archived in there. What's the purpose of that directory? I'd like to delete it as it's taking up over 900 MB, but I don't know what it's for, and googling did not help. Evidently they have it so well hidden that few people have noticed it before.

Comment: I have the same problem, but mine is over 65 GB

Comment: Removed with Finder.

Answer (score 12):

Just `rm -rf` it? That's how I removed mine.

Answer (score 10):

These apparently are temporary files associated with Xcode, but they don't seem to get cleaned up via a reboot. I followed the advice in this [OSX Daily](http://osxdaily.com/2016/01/13/delete-temporary-items-private-var-folders-mac-os-x/) article and was able to clean up the folder by simply **booting into safe mode**. Just hold down shift while your computer is booting. Be prepared for it to take a few minutes. The folder was completely removed after safe booting.

Comment: THANK YOU - I just saved an inordinate amount of space by doing this (somewhere in the region of 50GB).  Many years of Xcode installs (amoung other stuff) were obviously flushed, thank you so much.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to result in any files being cleaned up as of Mac OS Mojave.

Comment: Same problem with MacOS Catalina, a safe mode boot does not do the trick. What else can we try?